# Why does anonymous class can be use as argument?

Tags: java, android

Consider the following code:

```
test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);

test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // Do something 
}
```

}

So I am confuse because `new View.OnClickListener(){}`declares an anonymous class but shouldn't class not be allows to be used as argument? I thought only object can do that so why is this anonymous class emphasis on class be use as an argument? Also, if the class is use as argument, how does the method get invoked?

Comment: See the new keyword it's an object and not a Class instance, you define an anonymous class but it's object is passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is the object passed as an argument, not a class. `new View.OnClickListener()` is a statement to create an *object*.
What could mislead you is just that you're defining a method in-place, but you have to do it since `View.OnClickListener` is an abstract class and does not provide an implementation for `onClick()` method.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering but I am not so sure what you mean by View.OnClickListener does not provide an implementation for onClick() method. I thought that it does and that is why I have to override the onClick() method because when an interface is implemented, a method of that interface must be override.

Comment: @AnotherRandomUser When I say "does not provide an implementation" I mean that it does not have a method body inside that interface so you have to implement (write the method body) it by yourself. The interface *declares* the method, but does not *implement* it.

Answer (score 0):

Here anonymous class is not going as argument but new is creating a object or buffer and providing the reference of that buffer as a argument.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `new View.OnClickListener()` you create an object so you are not using a class as an argument. It's ok. You just not save the link into some **variable** (create by you own) but the link now is **saved into your button object** so it will not be lost and garbige collector will not destroy you listener.

Method is invoded as it always happens.